# Keymap changed Enter key function to Backspace

Tags: opensuse, keymap

I have a user account on SUSE 10 which connects via an SSH (F-Secure/PuTTY) client.

All of a sudden the mapping for my <kbd>↲ Enter</kbd> key isn't working as usual - instead it is acting as a <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> key.

How can I reconfigure it back to normal? Here's what I've tried:

- Loaded `us.map.gz` using `loadkeys` as root
- Checked `stty` settings on another SUSE box: no difference

Comment: Have you tried bash with "--norc"? Are you sure it's not a binding in the shell? Try ssh'ing from a Linux machine, and if that brings up the same problem, run "ssh machinename bash --norc" (It won't show any command prompt markers, so just start typing things, e.g. "ls", "exit").